# Loading an image to a canvas from the local filesystem prior to upload

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-canvas

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and can't get my head around the follow browser compatibility issue:

The following works beautifully in Chrome, IE and Opera (haven't tried safari yet) but refuses to work in Firefox. I have searched hi and low for objects and properties that aren't supported in Firefox that I have called in, but can't find any.

Anyway, here is the code:

```
<input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='loadImg(event)'><br>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas><br>
<button type="button">Upload</button><br>

<script>
var loadImg = function(event) {
    var input = event.target;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

    reader.onloadend = function() {
        var dataURL = reader.result;
        var output = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = output.getContext('2d');
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.src = dataURL;
        context.drawImage(imageObj,1,1,198,198);
    }       
}
</script>
```

Comment: what is the output ? Please be more precise...

Comment: The output is to draw a selected image from the filesystem to a canvas element on the page prior to uploading to a server as an avatar for user profiles.

For the purpose of this you should ignore the upload button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your image is not loaded yet when you draw it on your canvas.
 You can do it like this:

```
<input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='loadImg(event)'><br>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas><br>
<button type="button">Upload</button><br>

<script>
var loadImg = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = output.getContext('2d');
    var input = event.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        var dataURL = reader.result;
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.src = dataURL;
        imageObj.onload=function(){
            context.drawImage(imageObj,1,1,198,198);
        }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);


}
</script>
```

The `imageObj.onload` callback will be executed when the image is loaded. It seems firefox doesn't load immediately data-uri images whereas chrome does...

Comment: Thankyou for the help. I appreciate it. So to avoid this in the future can you talk me through the difference, I see you clear the canvas before redrawing it, you have also added a new 'imageObj.onload = function()' I dont understand the purpose of this. Thanks again.

Comment: the important part is the `imageObj.onload=function(){...}` others are just things I added to try your code,  the onload handler is triggered when the image is loaded and so render the canvas.

Comment: OK I get it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: please, select as best answer if it helped.

Comment: First time posting, best answer selected.